# A property that changes a from var to val once a none null value is assigned?

Tags: kotlin

Would it be useful if Kotlin will add a property that once assigned with a none null value a var property would be changed to val, means you cannot change the value anymore?

```
val? context Context? = null
...
...
...
context = this
...
...
...
context = this.applicationContext //would be an error since context   
                                  //is val
```

Above is just an example of how useful it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be what you really want in this case:

```
val context:Context by lazy { this }
```

Answer (score 2):

All kinds of properties with "special" behaviour are handled with [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

All feature request should go though [the official Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT). Actually, there is already a request [KT-7180](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7180) for what you have suggested.

Here is a possible implementation (from the issue):

```
class InitOnceVar<T>() : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private var initialized = false
    private var value: T? = null

    override fun get(thisRef: Any?, desc: PropertyMetadata): T {
        if (!initialized) throw IllegalStateException("Property ${desc.name} should be initialized before get")
        return value
    }

    override fun set(thisRef: Any?, desc: PropertyMetadata, value: T) {
        if (initialized) throw IllegalStateException("Property ${desc.name} could be initialized only once")
        this.value = value
        initialized = false
    }
}
```

Here is how you use it:

```
var x: String by InitOnceVar()
x = "star"
x = "stop"  //Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible already:

```
fun test() {
  val s : String

  println(s) // Error: Variable 's' must be initialized

  s = "Hello"
  println(s)

  s = "World!" // Error: Val cannot be reassigned
}
```

Otherwise, there is no possible way to do this. For example, if you want this as a member property, the compiler can't possibly know whether or not a method has been called before and if the assignment is allowed.

@ligi's answer is a nice alternative.

Comment: I mean a  property dude and not a variable inside a function. A property is  always asking for initialization.